# error: multiple repeat at position while using a regex pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm using a regex to replace any string that appears after the word username followed by a `(:` or `;)` with optional spaces with one optional space in between.

I use the below regex in PHP:

```
(?i)\bUsername\s?+(:|;)\s?+\K\S+
```

However I wanted to know how to use the same expression in python as I get the error: `error: multiple repeat at position 17"`.

Below is my testcase and I wanted to extract only `dasdsad` from all the examples.

Any ways to achieve this in Python?

```
Username:dasdsad
username ;dasdsad
username : dasdsad
username; dasdsad
```

Comment: multiple repeat is probably `?+`. Which one is it? probably only `?`

Comment: Python does not support `?+` or `\K` You could use a cpaturing group instead `\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*(\S+)` https://regex101.com/r/hW8BUf/1 I think if you use the pypi regex module it will work using `(?i)\bUsername\h*[:;]\h*\K\S+` https://regex101.com/r/1uMaYS/1

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use re.sub() on the pattern to replace only 'dasdsad' with another string say 'username'. When I try to use your pattern it replaces the whole 'username; dasdsad'. Any way to only replace the occurrence after username.

Comment: If you use the regex module https://tio.run/##hc89C8IwEAbgPb/iuCnR4uLWIiKlkx@IH5MRSWnQDk1L7gr662OQFtx6y8vBM7xv9@FX65Yh1E3XegZvn/YtRGeYrXewAo9yXStdXin@prGaZrc0u8fQW32eoxBsiR/EPmKJI0srQxWZSjsU8HfYDwCySZHCFMlGgSp29rVj@RuwoL6Uw4YE8FQcd5u82BeHCyYw9lUqhC8

Comment: python has no notion of possesive quantifiers `\s?+` or this construct `\K` whicsh is treated as literal K. So, what are you trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

```
(?i)\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*(\S+)
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/ftNHVe/1). Instead of `\K`, use capturing group, `(\S+)` will capture one or more non-whitespace characters into a group.

Python [demo code](https://regex101.com/r/ftNHVe/1/codegen?language=python):

```
import re

regex = r"(?i)\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*(\S+)"

test_str = ("Username:dasdsad\n"
    "username ;dasdsad\n"
    "username : dasdsad\n"
    "username; dasdsad")

print( re.findall(regex, test_str) )
```

**UPDATE:**

To replace and keep part of match use

```
test_str = re.sub(r'(?i)(\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*)\S+', r'\1username', test_str)
```

If you need to replace with digit:

```
test_str = re.sub(r'(?i)(\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*)\S+', r'\g<1>1234', test_str)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to use re.sub() on the pattern to replace only 'dasdsad' with another string say 'username'. When I try to use your pattern it replaces the whole occurrence 'username: dasdsad' to 'username'. Any way to only replace the occurrence 'dasdsad'.

Comment: @dmorgan Yes, see update. You should use capturing groups round the part you need to keep.

Comment: @dmorgan Please kindly upvote my answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 2):

Python does not support possessive quantifiers or `\K`.

If you want to replace the matches, you don't need `\s?+`.

You could use `\s*` and use `\K`, and make use of the [regex pypi module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) and use regex.sub

```
\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*\K\S+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MsCv1h/1) | [Python demo](https://tio.run/##hc89C8IwEAbgPb/iuCnR4uLWIiKlkx@IH5MRSWnQDk1L7gr662OQFtx6y8vBM7xv9@FX65Yh1E3XegZvn/YtRGeYrXewAo9yXStdXin@prGaZrc0u8fQW32eoxBsiR/EPmKJI0srQxWZSjsU8HfYDwCySZHCFMlGgSp29rVj@RuwoL6Uw4YE8FQcd5u82BeHCyYw9lUqhC8)

```
import regex

pattern = r"(?i)\bUsername\s*[:;]\s*\K\S+"

test_str = ("Username:dasdsad\n"
            "username ;dasdsad\n"
            "username : dasdsad\n"
            "username; dasdsad")

print(regex.sub(pattern, "REPLACEMENT", test_str))
```

Output

```
Username:REPLACEMENT
username ;REPLACEMENT
username : REPLACEMENT
username; REPLACEMENT
```

Comment: Thank you and I made use of the above solution and would keep a note of this as well